# how to create pagination if api has not provided any option (data items per page)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

All I get from an api is an array of objects, there is no pages or anything that I can use to request only part of the data. I wonder if there is still a good way to create pagination on my client?

(Im using react)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't save on network data-transfers or parsing (although some lazy parsing algorithm might help), paging would improve the memory footprint of all the DOM nodes created, and the time it takes to layout the page.

If you are really conscious about those aspects I would consider using something like [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) to lazy-render data.

The primary considerations of paging is saving on network transfers. The trick of lazy-rendering nodes makes sense on really large datasets.